# Самый продолжительный тренд

Tags: python

> Заполните список numbers нечетными числами от 11 до 27 включительно. Используйте цикл while.

Я написал так:

```
numbers = 11
while numbers <= 27:
    if numbers % 2 != 0: 
        print(numbers)
        numbers += 1
```

Задача работает, числа выходят как надо, но не списком.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить?

Comment: отформатируй нормально код, а то непонятно, что ты там написал. И какая связь между заголовком и тем, что в вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

ну в задаче же список надо. а не просто принт

```
numbers = []
i = 11
while i <= 27:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        numbers.append(i) 
    i += 1

print(numbers)
```

ну или так через `for`

```
numbers = [i for i in list(range(11,28)) if i % 2 != 0 ]
```

Comment: range может принимать три параметра, из которых третий - шаг. Тогда не потребуется проверять на четность. range(11,28,2)

Comment: так тогда и цикл не нужен будет)) все это еще в `list()`

Comment: `while True:
    print(list(range(11,28,2)))
    break` вот и цикл while есть и список получили

Answer (score 1):

Вам достаточно сделать переменную которая будет списком, и при каждой итерации добавлять туда новое значение

```py
number = 11
list_data = []
while number <= 27:
    if number % 2 != 0: 
        print(number)
        list_data.append(number)
    number += 1
```